# Removes and returns the first occurrence of the specified string in array using Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I am trying to delete from an array the first occurence, not all elements like the searched element The array is something like:

```
 String[] names = {"Becky", "Rosa", "Tina", "Jill", "Rosa", "Bill"};
```

And I want to be able to say remove(Rosa) and only find and remove the first element in the array named Rosa.

Comment: Might want to qualify what you mean by `delete`, and consider using a `List`.

Comment: your example doesn't even compile.

Comment: it was just an example, it wasn't from anything @djechlin

Comment: The same question is asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940337/remove-a-specific-string-from-an-array-of-string

Comment: @Mr.M, Thanks! It didn't show up when I searched for it.

Comment: @djechlin:  What about that array declaration is invalid syntax?

Answer (score 1):

So you might want to consider using an `Arraylist` for dynamic removal and resizing

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


ArrayList<string> persons = new ArrayList<string>();
persons.add("Becky");
//... adding in people to the list

//then if you want to remove  someone name "becky"
persons.removeall.(collection.singleton("Becky"))
```

Comment: Use a `while` loop to remove all Beckys `while(persons.remove("Becky");

Comment: don't have to use a while, can just use `removeall`

Comment: But then you have to deal with collections.

Comment: Not like thats a big deal `removeall.(collection.singleton("Becky"))`

Comment: Too-shay, I have never done Collections before so I had no idea, you should change your post to `removeAll` instead of `while`

Comment: Done. I mean it didn't matter no upvotes neway lol